# How does Python's garbage collector deal with items in a list?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

If I do:

```
def foo():
    a = [np.random.randn(10) for _ in range(100)]
    return a[-1]
b = foo()
```

Does Python's garbage collector free the first 99 items in `a` when it kicks in? Or does it consider the whole array as being referenced and keeps all 100 items in memory while b is being used?

Comment: I suspect the garbage collector will be invoke after the function is popped off the stack. So, I think consider the whole array as being referenced and keeps it in memory until the garbage collector is invoked. I could be wrong

Comment: CPython uses reference counting for as its main automatic memory management strategy, with an auxiliary cyclic garbage collector to deal with cyclic references. Reference counting "kicks in" immediately, i.e., objects are freed *the moment their reference count reaches 0*.  There is no array here, btw, you mean a `list`. The list object is no longer referenced when `foo` terminates,  and the items in a list do not know they are being referenced by the list, so the list object is freed. So no.

Comment: But I'm assuming Python doesn't create 100 references when I create `a` right? Does this mean a new reference is created the moment I return `a[-1]` ?

Comment: Well, yes, your list referenes each of the 100 objects contained in `a`, how else would it work? Anyway, when you return `a[-1]` and assign it to `b = foo()`, then yes, you create another reference to that last item, so that one doesn't get garbage collected, but all the others do.

Comment: So, to be clear, there are not 100 references to the list.The list has references for the 100 objects you create that are contained inside the list. When the function terminates, the list reference count reaches 0, so the list is reclaimed, then the reference count of all but the last item, which you `return`, reach 0, and those 99 items are reclaimed.

Comment: well, I assume Python uses contiguous blocks of memory for lists to make indexing fast. Anyway, I think the conclusion is to stop worrying about it and have faith in the gc.

Comment: Yes, `list` objects are implemented as dynamic arrays, so there is an array of PyObject pointers if you dig into the C-internals, but I'm not sure why that is relevant. Regardless of how it would be implemented, you would need at least one reference to each of the items in the list for it to be able to work.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collection mechanism is related to reference counts. When an object is no more reachable, the garbage collector free the associated memory.
In this case, after `return` you will no longer be able to reach `a` and the objects inside, so yes: Python's garbage collector free the first 99 items.

However, I cannot say the speed with which this happens...

Comment: In CPython, objects are freed immediately when their reference count reaches zero. Of course, that is an implementation detail of CPython. JYthon, for example, relies on the JVM garbage collector.